# Android sending data to restful webservices

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, http-post

I am trying to send data from android smartphone to a restful webservice made in java using jersey library.

I saw the following answer on how to do it:

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "Hi"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Although this seems about right i have a doubt in the `nameValuePairs` variable.
Particularly in this part:

```
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
```

If i have a webservice that has the following signature:

```
@POST
@Path("/post/location")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createLocation(Loc location)
```

what would be the `"id"` part in the `nameValuePairs` variable, it would be location or Loc?.

Comment: using what technology you're web service was build?

Comment: Jersey 1.18 library and genson to deserialize objects

Comment: what response do you get when you execute your app on android? what error?

Comment: right now i am getting connection refused. but this is a question i would like to see answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    //
    String url = 'url_to_you_server_api.dev/postservice'

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();

    params.put("id","id");
    params.put("hi","hi");

    StringEntity jsonEntity = new StringEntity( params.toString() );

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

    request.addHeader("Content-Type","application/json");

    request.setEntity(jsonEntity);

    response = client.execute(request);
```

if you service receive a entity it might be a json or something not just key-value params that correspond to form-data.

Comment: You use StringEntity which places the json object in a weird format with \" to allow for the " inside the string. Which i dont want to use . i want to send the json string exactly has it is given to me by the Gson

Comment: so just build you own json? "{ 'id':'id','hi':'value'}"

Comment: I can do the JSON part all correct but how can i send just a string has i have it to a webservice of that type? Is there another way, without using StringEntity?

Comment: ok this worked for me i used your answer to reach the final solution. thx. The part that saved me was reques.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); which i was previously adding to the StringEntity object and not the postrequest